# I post with ajax in the same page but i can't receive in php

Tags: php, ajax

I would post in the same page. For this i post with ajax. But i post and receive in the same page.

The code :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $("#menusecme1").on("change", function() {

                var deger = $("#menusecme1").val();

            $.ajax({ 

                url: "okulue.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    menu : deger
                },
                success: function(){



                }

            });
        });

</script>
```

İn success i created an alert function it working. So in this code have any problem.

The php code:

```
if (isset($_POST["menu"]) == 'yes') {
}

if (isset($_POST["menu"])) {
}
```

I tried this if. But they not work.

How can i resolve this problem?

I need your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Here is the SO guide to asking a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

`isset()` returns boolean and not what you have.

Below will help you test.

in php script, do this

```
echo isset($_POST['menu']) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

This will echo out yes should `$_POST['menu']` be set

Personally i would go for `empty()` as it also checks if the variable is also set.

```
echo !empty($_POST['menu']) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

Comment: I receive no. When i post i don't receive. Because i post without renewing the page

Comment: I receive no. When i post i don't receive. Because i post without renewing the page